# Coding for Entrepreneurs - Tracking Shares, "Join object" being displayed instead of entries

Tags: django

I'm watching the video course by Udemy "Coding for Entrepreneurs Learn Python, Django, and More." It's from 2015 so the code is outdated and I'm doing my best to update it and get it working properly. The origional code for the course is at "https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/launch-with-code." My altered code is displaying "Join object" in the Friend field for every entry instead of the friend's email. Below is the code that I am using.

The views.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from .forms import EmailForm, JoinForm
from .models import Join
import uuid


def get_ip(request):
    try:
        x_forward = request.META.get("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
        if x_forward:
            ip = x_forward.split(",")[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
    except:
        ip = ""
    return ip


def get_ref_id():
    ref_id = str(uuid.uuid4())[:11].replace('-', '').lower()
    try:
        id_exists = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)
        get_ref_id()
    except:
        return ref_id


def share(request, ref_id):
    try:
        join_obj = Join.objects.get(ref_id=ref_id)
        friends_referred = Join.objects.filter(friend=join_obj)
        count = join_obj.referral.all().count()
        ref_url = settings.SHARE_URL + str(join_obj.ref_id)
        context = {"ref_id": join_obj.ref_id, "count": count, "ref_url": ref_url}
        template = "share.html"
        return render(request, template, context)
    except:
        raise Http404


def home(request):
    try:
        join_id = request.session['join_id_ref']
        obj = Join.objects.get(id=join_id)
    except:
        obj = None

    form = JoinForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        new_join_old, created = Join.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            new_join_old.ref_id = get_ref_id()
            if not obj == None:
                new_join_old.friend = obj
            new_join_old.ip_address = get_ip(request)
            new_join_old.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/%s" % (new_join_old.ref_id))

    context = {"form": form}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    friend = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name='referral', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="ABC", unique=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="ABC")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.email)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("email", "ref_id",)
```

The forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Join


class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()


class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Join
        fields = ["email",]
```

The middleware.py file(in the folder with settings, not in the app folder like      the other files; is addressed in the settings.py file):

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from joins.models import Join


class ReferMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        ref_id = request.GET.get("ref")
        try:
            obj = Join.objects.get(ref_id = ref_id)
        except:
            obj = None      
        if obj:
            request.session['join_id_ref'] = obj.id

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        return response
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: when you say "displaying "Join object" in the Friend field " where is that? Your friend field is a Foreign Key to a Join object, so by default your Join object is printed as <Join object> in python3, using the `__repr__()` method. Which version of python are you using? Instead of `__unicode__()` you might want to create a `__str__()` method.

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1weOmrde6iaCgCMN8c1z1Q1PVSJpnZjmS)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vuYoy5Dw1jKApKvU2dsmbqFyqoXfXVSy

Comment: Above are 2 pictures showing what I'm talking about. At "http://127.0.0.1:7000/admin/joins/join/8/change/" it shows email, friend, ref id, and ip address. Instead of showing the other users unique info in friend they all say "Join object"

Comment: I tried to change __unicode__() to __str__() and got an error.                                          SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'joins.admin.JoinAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to '__unicode__', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'JoinAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'joins.Join'.

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: I was using python3. I got it to work using python2.7 by changing a few things. If by any chance you know how to make it work with python3 I would really appreciate it. Btw thank you for your so far.